# Scala: Creating a list of tuples from list elements sequentially

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, immutability

I am very new to Scala so this question may be very naive.

I have a list like this `List[Int] = List(0, 3, 6, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17)`. I am trying to create a list like this `[(0,3),(3,6),(6,12)..]` and so on. So far this is what I have tried:

```
val l1= List(0, 3, 6, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17)
var l2=scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Int,Int)]()
l1.zipWithIndex.slice(0,l1.length-1).foreach(x=>{val newval=(x._1,l1(x._2+1)); l2+=newval})
```

Two questions here:

1. If I don't use `val newval`, i.e. try to do `l1.zipWithIndex.slice(0,l1.length-1).foreach(x=>l2+=(x._1,l1(x._2+1)))`, the compiler says: 
   `<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
   found   : Int
   required: (Int, Int)
             l1.zipWithIndex.slice(0,l1.length-1).foreach(x=>l2+=(x._1,l1(x._2+1)))`. Why is that?
2. What would a way to do it without the mutable listbuffer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. `+=` is a method on the `ListBuffer` `l2` that accepts repeated parameters. That means when you do something like this:

   ```
   scala> var l2 = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Int, Int)]()
   l2: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Int, Int)] = ListBuffer()

   scala> l2 += (1, 2)
   <console>:9: error: type mismatch;
    found   : Int(1)
    required: (Int, Int)
                 l2 += (1, 2)
   ```

.. The compiler thinks you are trying to add multiple `Int`s to the `ListBuffer`, when you are trying to add a tuple. You need an extra set of parentheses.

```
 l1.zipWithIndex.slice(0,l1.length-1).foreach(x=> l2 += ((x._1,l1(x._2+1)) ))
```

2. You can use `sliding`, which will create a "sliding window" across the collection to return a list of lists of a specific group size, with a step size of one by default:

   ```
   scala> List(0, 3, 6, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17).sliding(2)
              .map { case List(a, b) => (a, b) }.toList
   res10: List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,3), (3,6), (6,12), (12,14), (14,15), (15,16), (16,17))
   ```

Answer (score 3):

besides the sliding, you could slide like following:

```
  val l1= List(0, 3, 6, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17)
  val l2 = l1.take(l1.size - 1).zip(l1.tail)
```

updated

```
   l1.zip(l1.tail) works.
```

Comment: `size` may be `O(n)`, so I'd prefer `dropRight`, and then `drop` for symmetry

Comment: size is not O(n), but take is. I guess except head & tail, other methods on List are all O(n).

Comment: `l1.init` would be more idiomatic than `l1.take(l1.size - 1)`

Comment: @Paul you're right, I was mistaken about `dropRight`'s implementation. I was basically thinking of `Stream`'s implementation. Anyway, isn't the whole `take` part redundant as `zip` only takes commonly existing elements anyway? (even so, I agree that ensuring both lists have the same length is more readable)

Comment: Yes, `l1.zip(l1.tail)` is all that's needed